# How to use terminal from Krusader with LXDE?

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, lxde, krusader

I am using Krusader 2.4.0-beta3 on Lubuntu 14.04. When I try to run the "Start Terminal Here" command with default settings I get

> Error executing
>
> konsole --workdir %d!

I want to start lxterminal, so I modified General | General | Terminal in settings to

> lxterminal --working-directory %d

Now nothing happens after using "Start Terminal Here" or "Start Terminal"

How can I start lxterminal from Krusader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a space, put `=` between the argument and %d

```
lxterminal --working-directory=%d
```